# Why do Blade directive examples are showing echo and don't just return a string?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

What I have found [on the internet](https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-about-writing-custom-blade-directives).

```
\Blade::directive('hello', function ($expression) {
    list($greet, $name) = explode(', ', $expression);

    return "<?php echo {$greet} . ' ' . {$name}; ?>";
});
```

It feels here that at runtime the function will be called. Then why not just doing

```
\Blade::directive('hello', function ($expression) {
    list($greet, $name) = explode(', ', $expression);

    return $greet . ' ' . $name;
});
```

I have seen many example following the `return "<?php echo ..."` pattern and I don't really get the point.

EDIT to clarify from the comments and answers, **key assumptions are in bold**:

In the first example, $expression is exploded in the function, I am wondering, how can Blade dynamically explode just from the returned php code? Such code makes me believe that **both directive function and returned code are run at each rendering**?

Secondly, if the **return statement** contains PHP opening tags, I guess **it is processed as a standard PHP script**, so why not returning a string?

Comment: The following `return "<?php echo {$greet} . ' ' . {$name}; ?>";` is the final result that suppose to replace the directive. If you just return then there'll be nothing. It's you handler's responsibility to do what you want to do.

Comment: @TheAlpha I have made a small edit to clarify

Comment: Only one rending occurs, that is the rendering of the blade file which is what you see in the browser. Think of it as a PHP script that produces a (dynamic) PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

The returned string from directives is passed through the Blade Compiler prior to rendering. It is generating executable PHP script files that the server can process.

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html

Have a look at the cached files in `storage/framework/views` to see the end result.

Comment: Thanks, I have made an edit in the question (I will check in the cache to understand better).